# Pass Strings into User Defined Function with Modeling

Tags: r, dplyr, regression, user-defined-functions

Trying to pass the name of a variable into a user defined regression function. Having a heck of a time. Here is the formula, run prior to converting it into a function:

```
# Run cox proportional hazards regressions  
survey::svycoxph(Surv(
    time = fu_time_PJP, 
    event = fu_status_PJP) ~ prophied,
    design = svydesign(
      ids = ~1,
      weights = ~wts,
      data = df_ptm),
    weights = wts,
    id = patient_id,
    data = df_ptm)


Call:
svycoxph(formula = Surv(time = fu_time_PJP, event = fu_status_PJP) ~ 
    prophied, design = svydesign(ids = ~1, weights = ~wts, data = df_ptm), 
    weights = wts, id = patient_id, data = df_ptm)

            coef exp(coef) se(coef) robust se      z     p
prophied -0.8243    0.4386   0.7744    0.9549 -0.863 0.388

Likelihood ratio test=  on 1 df, p=
n= 862, number of events= 5
```

Works great... BUT I have to run about a dozen of these and would like to be able to specify the variables (ie fu_time_XVAR, fu_status_XXX). Cannot for the life of me figure out how to do it. Have tried this a dozen times, including naming the variable within the UDF, passing variables in various {{}} or [[]] or [,x] ways, enquo(), parse(paste)), etc.

No matter what I do I get various "Error... all variables must be in design." In simple terms, the following is what I want to do, though obviously this formulation doesn't work.

```
# Run cox proportional hazards regressions  
cox_fun <- function(x) {
  survey::svycoxph(Surv(
    time = paste0("fu_time_", x), 
    event = paste0("fu_status_", x) ~ prophied,
    design = svydesign(
      ids = ~1,
      weights = ~wts,
      data = df_ptm),
    weights = wts,
    id = patient_id,
    data = df_ptm)
}

cox_fun("PJP")
```

Would greatly appreciate any help!

Comment: Can you compile your `fu_time_` and `fu_status` objects into a data frame, or into two lists? If so, you can edit your `cox_fun` to take two inputs and use `mapply(FUN = cox_fun, x = df$time, y = df$status)`?    Otherwise, I think you need to look at using `do.call()` so that your `Paste0`ed strings are interpreted as variable names.

Comment: Try wrapping each `paste0()` result in `get()`.

Comment: I tried get and it didn't work. The idea of altering the varialbes within the dataframe was a good one and fixed it. I actually just renamed the variables within the dataframe prior to entering the function. Not elegant, but works

Comment: df_lim <- df_ptm %>% 
    rename(fu_time = paste0("fu_time_", {{x}})) %>% 
    rename(fu_status = paste0("fu_status_", {{x}}))